# I want to emulate a Samsung Galaxy S10+, but skins don't emulate the behavior

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, samsung-mobile

I want to emulate Samsung devices, and found a couple of skins, inputted the screen sizes and the resolutions, and when I finish, I find the OS is different than that of a real device - things work a lot differently on a Samsung device. For example, a real Samsung S10+ has a home screen that might look like:

[image]

The feel is very different than that of say, Google Pixel 3. Also notice navigation is different too. That's enough to convince me the behavior will be different. Here's what the emulator looks like:

[image]

Different, no?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPDATE: Samsung has released some Emulator Skins. I don't know if they will make the emulator behave in the same way as a physical Samsung device, but they appear to make them cosmetically look correct.
https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-emulator-skin/guide.html

Comment: Not sure exactly what source you are looking for here?. The Android Emulator, which is owned by Google/AOSP, is a separate entity from Samsung. To my knowledge Samsung hasn't released its own system images to the public. https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds

Comment: Thank you. Please add this to your answer so I can accept it

Comment: Although correct about skins, @prfarlow's answer does not answer the OP's question - how to emulate the Samsung hardware.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to emulate a Samsung device. Android Studio only lets you emulate the stock Android OS.

Emulator Skins just change the appearance of the device frame.